# Proving that a sequence diverges to -inf

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that the divergence of the following sequence.
$$s_n= -2n^{\frac{9}{8}}$$

To prove this I was thinking of starting with $$n^{\frac{9}{8}} > n$$

Then, $$2n^{\frac{9}{8}} > 2n$$

Then, $$-2n^{\frac{9}{8}} < -2n$$.

Then proving that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}-2n = -\infty$$

And since $$-2n^{\frac{9}{8}} < -2n$$, by comparison, $$s_n= -2n^{\frac{9}{8}}$$ diverges.

I know there is more than one way to prove divergent of a sequence such as using contradiction of convergence using epsilon... Etc. But does my method count as a valid proof? I also tried proving this using the odd and even integer subsequence to prove this but I got stuck. Thanks.

Comment: look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathjax tutorial

Comment: What you is completely valid but need a proof(if $a_n<b_n$ and $b_n\to-\infty$ then $a_n\to-\infty$ need a proof)

Comment: No. $f(n) < g(n)$ and $g(n) \to -\infty$ does not imply $f(n) \to -\infty$ since $\lim f(n)$ might not exist at all.

Comment: It actually does. Let $M$ a real number. Choose $N$ s.t. $g(n) < M$ for all $n >N$. Then $f(n) < M$ for all $n > N$ and $f(n) \to - \infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is completely correct. In the comments, I provided a proof for the fact:

$$a_n < b_n, b_n \to -\infty \implies a_n \to -\infty$$ which you used implicitely in your proof.